# Vuex does not commit changes until it's committed manually via dev tools

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a vuex store module called login.js as below

```
import axios from "axios";
import router from "@/router";

axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT;

const state = {
  access_token: localStorage.getItem("access_token") || null,
};

const getters = {
  loggedIn() {
    return (
      state.access_token != null && localStorage.getItem("access_token") != null
    );
  }
};

const mutations = {
  doLogin(state, response) {
    const token = response.authentication_data.access_token;
    localStorage.setItem("access_token", token);
    state.access_token = token;
    router.push("/admin");
  };

const actions = {
  async getToken({ commit }, userdata) {
    let email = userdata.email;
    let password = userdata.password;
    let remember_me = userdata.remember_me;

    await axios
      .post("auth/login", null, {
        params: {
          email,
          password,
          remember_me
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.meta.status == "true") {
          commit("doLogin", response.data);
        } else {
          alert("wrong password");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

login.vue code

```
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getToken"]),
    login() {
      const userdata = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        remember_me: true
      };

      this.getToken(userdata);
    }
  }
```

The login function works and the token is set for the 1st time but when I refresh the browser the `access_token` is gone.

In the browser, it's shown as below

[image]

But if I commit via dev tools it works and the state becomes persistent.

The similar nature questions on SO but don't answer this question.

[vuex commit does not commit to store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294030/vuex-commit-does-not-commit-to-store)

[Vue2 + Vuex Commit Not Committing (without Vue devtools)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893923/vue2-vuex-commit-not-committing-without-vue-devtools?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Vuex Mutation running, but component not updating until manual commit in vue dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52865612/vuex-mutation-running-but-component-not-updating-until-manual-commit-in-vue-dev)

How can I make the `state.access_token` persistent via the code? The problem is with a page refresh I lost `state.access_token` value.

Comment: Try using this https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate, I use it in my store>index.js like this:

import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'


Vue.use(Vuex)

// Create a new store
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      getState: (key) => Cookies.getJSON(key),
      setState: (key, state) => Cookies.set(key, state, {
        expires: 3,
        secure: false
      })
    })
  ],
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations,
  state
})

but you can use localStorage instead of cookies

Comment: npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: @Sdpotts93 This is not about local storage rather `state.access_token`

Comment: @Techie Which you need to store in *local storage* if you want it to persist after a page refresh.

Comment: Please refer to the code sample. I have stored the access_token and retrieving as well

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine and Vuex is successfully "committing" your data to the store. The issue you're experiencing is coming from the fact that Vuex (out of the box) does not persist your data in localStorage, which I believe is what you mean by "commit". As has been mentioned a couple times in comments on your question, you are going to need to use a third party package (most people use [Vuex-PersistedState](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate), but I prefer [Vuex-Persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist) as it's more customizable and supports Typescript). Either one is very easy to get started with.

With Vuex-PersistedState, you'll need to update your Vuex initialization with the new plugin. It should look something like this:

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate' // import the package

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createPersistedState()] /// include the imported plugin
})
```

Comment: This is not about local storage rather `state.access_token`

Comment: For `state.accesstoken` to persist across a refresh, you need some sort of local storage, @Techie.

Comment: Please refer to the code sample. I have stored the access_token and retrieving as well

Comment: Can you share the code where "localStorage" is defined and initialized?